# What are your tips for finding a replacement battery for mac book pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery

The battery on my mac book pro (late 2008) running OS X Yosemite needs to be replaced. The battery only holds half capacity. What are your tips for finding a good battery. What battery do you recommend?

Comment: Have you looked at: (i) Apple stores on line, (ii) Apple resellers on line, (iii) other retailers on line, (iv) bricks & mortar stores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically all third party batteries for mac are s**t, go to Apple and buy an apple battery. Expensive but worth the money. I am speaking from a hard way of learning...
LS